# Return only an owned type from a trait method that can accept an owned or borrowed value as input

Tags: rust

I want to have a trait that can be implemented for `T` and `&T` but has methods that always return `T`.

What I would like to do is something like this

```rust
use std::borrow::ToOwned;

trait Foo<X: ToOwned> {
    fn f(&self, x: X) -> f64;
    
    fn g(&self) -> X::Owned;
}

struct Float(f64);

impl Foo<f64> for Float {
    fn f(&self, x: f64) -> f64 {
        x + self.0
    }
    
    fn g(&self) -> f64 {
        self.0 * 2.0
    }
}

struct List(Vec<f64>);

impl Foo<&Vec<f64>> for List {
    fn f(&self, x: &Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
        x.iter().sum()
    }
    
    // Error here - `&Vec<f64>` return type expected
    fn g(&self) -> Vec<f64> {
        self.0.iter().map(|&x| 2.0 * x).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let float = Float(2.0);
    println!("{} {}", float.f(3.0), float.g());
   
    let list = List(vec![0.0, 1.0, 2.0]);
    println!("{} {:?}", list.f(&vec![1.0, 2.0]), list.g());
}
```

I know that one option is to have a trait that defines the output type like so

```rust
trait FooReturn {
   type Output;
}

trait Foo<X: FooReturn> {
    fn f(&self, x: X) -> f64;

    fn g(&self) -> X::Output;
}
```

then implement the trait for all relevant types, but I was wondering if there was a more standard/robust way to do this.

Comment: `&'static Vec<f64>` is the `::Owned` version of `&'a Vec<f64>` it does compile like that. But this means you don't actually want the `ToOwned` trait for this probably.

Comment: Right. Is there a built in trait that does what I need? Or do you think I need to roll my own?

Comment: I really really think you do not need this. It doesn't seem like a very useful thing. The behavior of taking something by value and by reference is different. If its just so you can use it with copy types like numbers then taking by reference and dereferencing where you use it is probably optimized out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it once specialization is complete. Meanwhile, I couldn't even get a simple working example to compile on `1.55.0-nightly`.

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

trait MaybeOwned {
    type Owned;
}

default impl<X> MaybeOwned for X {
    type Owned = X;
}

impl<'a, X> MaybeOwned for &'a X {
    type Owned = X;
}

trait Foo<X: MaybeOwned> {
    fn f(&self, x: &X) -> f64;
    fn g(&self) -> <X as MaybeOwned>::Owned;
}
```